# Gnosis wallet app distribution

Tags: wallets, multisignature, gnosis

Gnosis wallet is the golden standard of Ethereum multisig wallets:

https://wallet.gnosis.pm/

To minimize the security risks, does Gnosis wallet have a static HTML ZIP distribution? (Install once, run locally with Parity/Geth). I remember that I saw a download link somewhere, but I cannot no longer find it.

Comment: Is this the link you are looking for? https://github.com/ConsenSys/MultiSigWallet

Comment: No, the source code bundle is useless for non-technical people. You need to have npm to run the wallet from the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a standalone version you can download [here](https://wallet-website.gnosis.pm/).